# How to use converted file of libsvm in r into svm function of e1071 package?

Tags: r, libsvm

1. I tried to convert libsvm file into r format using the following code:

> library(e1071)
>   read.matrix.csr("birds1")
>   
>   The content of the file is:

```
+1  1:0  2:1  3:0  
-1  1:1  2:0  3:1
-1  1:0  2:0  3:0
+1  1:1  2:1  3:0
-1  1:0  2:0  3:0
```

it gives me output as:

```
    $x
    An object of class "matrix.csr"
    Slot "ra":
    [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

    Slot "ja":
    [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

    Slot "ia":
    [1]  1  4  7 10 13 16

    Slot "dimension":
    [1] 5 3


    $y
    [1] +1 -1 -1 +1 -1
    Levels: -1 +1
```

How to use this output in svm function? or how to convert this output in data frame format?